# Could hot water from attic water lines cause deterioration of toilet flush valves?

Tags: water, toilet, plumbing-fixture, flushvlave

Both of my toilets started losing water in the tank within about a week of each other. They aren't leaking out of the toilet, so I assume it is the flush valve. I replaced the flapper on one, but it didn't do the trick.

This happened very shortly after we had my house re-piped with PEX lines through our attic. Since we are in Florida, the water gets pretty hot during the day. It occurred to me that toilet valves probably aren't designed for hot water.

On one hand, it seems coincidental that both toilets started leaking at the same time, and almost immediately after the re-pipe. On the other hand, they were likely installed at the same time by the previous owner, and fill valves gave out on both of them around the same time a few months before the re-pipe, so they could just be deteriorating at the same rate.

I don't want to replace the flush valves only to have them stop working again because they aren't made for hot water. Could the temperature of the water be responsible for the problem?

Comment: Providing pictures ([edit] your question) of the flush valves in question (remove the tank lid, take a picture inside) would help eliminate confusion like JACK had.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt the hot water is responsible for the leaking toilets. What's probably causing the problem is sediment from the re piping getting caught in the diaphragms of the flow valves and causing the leaks. You could try to disassemble them and clean them out or just replace them if you have the inexpensive ones. Some of the common inexpensive ones have repair kits that include all the replacement parts.

Is this a standard flush or a low gallon, jet flush? I was assuming a standard and misinterpreted the questions. Changing the flapper was a good guess but did you check the seat that the flapper sits on? That can get pitted with sediment too.

Comment: I had the quarter turn valves when we first had kids, they would only turn the faucet on or off so I reduced the flow by partially closing the quarter turn valves. It worked for years like that, as far as I know they have not been changed as we sold the home.

Comment: This is my plumbing ignorance, but googling leads me to think "flow valve" is either the same as "fill valve" or part of the fill valve. There isn't a leak in the fill valve so far as I can tell, and the water is draining out of the tank, which wouldn't be a fill valve problem unless it was leaking at the intake, which would be making a mess. I'm not sure how sediment would be causing a leak from the tank into the bowl/drain.

Comment: Is this a standard flush or a low gallon, jet flush?  I was assuming a standard and misinterpreted the questions. Changing the flapper was a good guess but did you check the seat that the flapper sits on? That can get pitted with sediment too.

Comment: It is not a jet flush. The seat that the flapper sits on doesn't seem to have pits or sediment build up. My assumption at this point is that the rubber gasket under the flapper seat is no longer watertight due to wear, or there is some other gap in the flush valve that is letting water through. As long as it seems unlikely that hot water would cause rubber gaskets to buckle and unseal, I can just replace the flush valve.

Answer (score 0):

> This happened very shortly after we had my house re-piped with PEX lines through our attic.

This could be the hint.

During pipe replacement, non-soluble particles got in the lines, that eventually will get stuck in the toilet valve.

To overcome this in the future use mesh filters.

[image: mesh]

Source https://www.caterdepot.com/P34133_p/p34133x.htm

Open the toilet supply hose (close the valve) and insert an mesh filter

Comment: Could you clarify how sediment would cause this problem? Which valve would it be getting stuck in that would cause water to drain out of the tank?